# Link to "Editing Help" is located under its image

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, design, editing-help

When you're asking a question on SO there's a "Editing help" link above and right.
However, the link is not on top of the image. I'm using firebug in the image below to mark where the link is.

This bug appears on every stack exchange site.

**I've only tested this on Firefox version 3.6.16.**

---

[image]

Comment: No repro in IE8/XP, perhaps Firefox specific?

Comment: Same in Firefox 4 on a Mac. The odd thing: the mouse hover is correct (the image changes when hovering it). But the mouse pointer does not change and one must click in the blue area indicated in the screenshot above. In that blue area the pointer *does* change into a hand, and then also still triggers the hover to change the image.

Comment: That's because the <a> tag is the only thing that has moved.

Comment: No repro on Chrome on Windows XP...

Comment: I noticed this two days ago and thought it was just me! Repro on Win7 64-bit with FF4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browsers disagreed on the precise placement of a `position: absolute` element that had no explicit `top` value set (Webkit kept it on the same line as the previous element, Firefox pushed it down).

This is fixed in the next version.