# Markdown Editing Help tooltip triggers on the top-right corner of the Editing textarea

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link to “Editing Help” is located under its image.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88326/link-to-editing-help-is-located-under-its-image)

Moving the mouse pointer on the top-right corner of the editing textarea, the tooltip triggers abruptly.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1982487973.png

Tested on:
FF 3.1.16
OSX 10.5.8

Comment: On Firefox 4.0.1, and Mac OS X 10.6, The help button appears as if the mouse is hovering over it, when the mouse cursor is really on  the top-right corner of the text area. It doesn't happen with Safari, though.

Comment: It also happens with Opera 11.10. The problem is that, if I click on the top-right corner to select a word, the help page appears, as if the mouse was exactly hovering on the help button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browsers disagreed on the precise placement of a `position: absolute` element that had no explicit `top` value set (Webkit kept it on the same line as the previous element, Firefox pushed it down).

This is fixed in the next version.